# Why does things travel in a straight line in inertial frames?

Tags: general-relativity, classical-mechanics, geodesics, inertia, equivalence-principle

Why does physical entities travel in straight paths in a flat space-time and in geodesic in curved spacetime? Is it due to Inertia? If it is, then why does waves also follow the same pattern?

Comment: Consider mentioning how you define inertial frames in curved spacetimes.

Answer (score 1):

A free-falling particle follows a straight line independently whether a spacetime is flat or curved. What matters is how you define a straight line!

A straight line is defined as a curve which parallel transports its tangent vector.

In a flat spacetime (Minkowski) that definition matches with the intuitive concept of a straight line as the path of a light ray in our ordinary three dimensional space. In a curved manifold it is a geodesic obeying to the parallel transport constraint.

The geodesic equation is
$(D/d\lambda) (dx^\mu/d\lambda) = (dx^\nu/d\lambda) \nabla_\nu (dx^\mu/d\lambda) = 0$
where:
$D/d\lambda$ directional covariant derivative
$dx^\mu/d\lambda$ tangent vector
$\nabla_\mu$ covariant derivative
$\lambda$ affine parameter

Note: Both a massive particle and a massless one (photon) follow a geodesic.

Comment: I understand that. My question was why does it follow the straight line?

Comment: It’s a postulate!  This is Newton’s first law.

Comment: It is a definition. A straight line is the path of a particle not subject to any force. In flat spacetime it is Newton's first law, as reported by Cham. In a curved manifold is the geodesic equation. Note that in general relativity gravity is not described as a force, but as curvature.